How to solve linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients?
I have encountered a problem solving this equation:
$$
x^{4}\operatorname{y}’’\left(x\right) - \operatorname{y}\left(x\right) = 0
$$

I have already checked the answer with $\tt Wolfram$, but the question remains.
How to solve LDE with polynomial coefficients in
general ?.
I know that the basis of such equations have dimension $n$ where $n$ is the order of equation and the only way to solve them is to guess the solutions and use Liouville Ostrogradsky's Theorem or similar.
But what type of solution should I try to guess ?.


It's not so much that the coefficients are polynomial but that the equation is singular, and not in the regular fashion. You could try $y(x)=u(x^{-1})$, perhaps the equation for $u$ is simpler. You can expect terms like $\exp(x^{-1})$ and worse in a symbolic solution, if one exists at all.

I would say that the two main approaches are : $(1)$ guessing/ansatz + Wronskian, or $(2)$ change of variable $z(x) = y(1/x)$ + Frobenius method.

@Abezhiko but how exactly do I have to understand that I need to use substitution $z(x)=y(1/x)$ and what is Frobenius method about?

Frobenius method is (mostly) a fancy name for "find a series solution". The issue here is the singular nature of the ODE as noted above, which poses problems for series solutions. But the ODE you get using $w=1/x$ is not subject to this issue.

Thank you! @Semiclassical

As this equation has an essential singularity at $x=0$ it might help to shift that singularity to infinity. Thus insert $y(x)=u(t)=u(1/x)$,
$$
y'(x)=-\frac1{x^2}u'(1/x)\\
y''(x)=\frac1{x^4}u''(1/x)+\frac2{x^3}u'(1/x)
$$
to get to the equation
$$
u''(t)+\frac2tu'(t)-u(t)=0
$$
which has (nearly) the form of a Bessel equation but can be "compressed" more easily and directly as
$$
(tu(t))''-tu(t)=0.
$$
This now is a simple linear DE with well-known basis solutions $tu(t)=e^{\pm t}$. So indeed as found in the other answers
$$
y(x)=x(ce^{1/x}+de^{-1/x}).
$$

Writing the ode as (for non zero $x$)
\begin{equation}
x^{2}y^{\prime\prime}-\frac{y}{x^{2}}=0\tag{1}%
\end{equation}
Comparing the above to the generalized form of the Bessel ode given by Bowman (1958) as
\begin{equation}
x^{2}y^{\prime\prime}+\left(  1-2\alpha\right)  xy^{\prime}+\left(  \beta
^{2}\gamma^{2}x^{2\gamma}-n^{2}\gamma^{2}+\alpha^{2}\right)  y=0\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Which has the known standard solution
\begin{equation}
y=x^{\alpha}\left(  c_{1}\operatorname{BesselJ}\left(  n,\beta\,x^{\gamma
}\right)  +c_{2}\operatorname{BesselY}\left(  n,\beta\,x^{\gamma}\right)
\right)  \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Comparing (1) to (2) and solving algebraically for $\alpha,\beta,n,\gamma$
gives
\begin{align*}
\alpha &  ={\frac{1}{2}}\\
\beta &  =i\\
n &  ={\frac{1}{2}}\\
\gamma &  =-1
\end{align*}
Substituting all the above into (3) gives the solution as
$$
y=\sqrt{x}\left(  c_{1}\operatorname{BesselJ}\left(  {\frac{1}{2}},\frac
{i\,}{x}\right)  -c_{2}\operatorname{BesselY}\left(  {\frac{1}{2}},\frac
{i\,}{x}\right)  \right)
$$
Using known relations with normal trig functions the above can be written as
$$
y=\sqrt{x}\left(  c_{1}\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{i}{x}}}%
\sinh\left(  \frac{1}{x}\right)  +c_{2}\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt
{\frac{i}{x}}}\cosh\left(  \frac{1}{x}\right)  \right)
$$
Merging all constants
\begin{align*}
y  & =\sqrt{x}\left(  c_{3}\frac{i}{\sqrt{\frac{i}{x}}}\sinh\left(  \frac
{1}{x}\right)  +c_{4}\frac{i}{\sqrt{\frac{i}{x}}}\cosh\left(  \frac{1}
{x}\right)  \right)  \\
& =\sqrt{x}\left(  c_{3}\frac{i\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{i}}\sinh\left(  \frac{1}
{x}\right)  +c_{4}\frac{i\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{i}}\cosh\left(  \frac{1}{x}\right)
\right)  \\
& =c_{5}x\sinh\left(  \frac{1}{x}\right)  +c_{6}x\cosh\left(  \frac{1}
{x}\right)
\end{align*}

In TeX
With the differential equations for the chain rule
$$\frac{d}{dx}= \frac{dt}{dx}\ \frac{d}{dt} = \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}} \ \frac{d}{dt} $$
$$x^4 y''(x) \ - \ y(x) \quad 
   \rightarrow 
   \left( x \ = \ t^n,\ t \ = \ x^{1/n},  y(x) \ = \ u(t)\right) \rightarrow\quad 
  t^{4n}\  \left( \frac{1}{\partial_t \ x} \right) \partial_t \ 
    \left(  \frac{1}{\partial_t \ x}\  u'(t)\right) $$
yielding
$$\frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \left( t^{m+2 n+2}\cdot y''(t) \ + \ (2 m-n+1)\cdot t^{m+2 n+1}\cdot y'(t) \ + \ (t^m\cdot \left(m (m-n) t^{2 n}-n^2\right)\cdot y(t) \right)=0$$
Setting $n=2m+1$ removes the first derivative terms
$$t^{4 (m+1)}\cdot y''(t)\ + \ \left(-\left((m+1)\  m \ t^{4 m+2}\right)-(2 m+1)^2\right)\cdot y(t)=0$$
Now, setting $m=1$ yields the trivial equation $$y''-y=0$$
and so with $n=-1$ on has the usual two solutions of the linear constant coefficient equation
$$y(x) = a\  x \ e^{\pm \frac{1}{x} }$$
And then there is the 'energy trick':
$$\begin{align}
&x^4 y''-y=0\\
&x^4 y' y''-y y'=0\\
&(x^2 y'(x))^2 - y(x)^2 = c_1\\
&\frac{d}{dx}= \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}} \ \frac{d}{dt}\\
&\frac{x(t)^2}{x'(t)} \ v'(t)^2\ - \ v(t)^2 \ = \  c_1
\end{align}$$
with
$$y(x(t)) = v(t),  \quad x'(t) = x(t)^2,  \quad x(t)=\frac{1}{c_2-t}$$
The equation for v is now the simple first oder equation for exponentials $(c=0)$ and hyperbolic functions $c_2^2\gt 0,\ -c_2^2\lt 0 $
$$v'2-v^2 = \pm c_2^2 $$

How do you integrate $x^4(y'^2)'-(y^2)'=0$ to the form that you got? And in the first approach, where there no first derivative terms from that substitution?
